# I'm trying to group a series of controls in an ASP.NET webform and perform a calculation on all of them using c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2019

This may be easier than I am making it out to be, but either way I am completely stumped. I have created an ASP.NET webform in Visual Studio 2019 and I am trying to find a way to loop through a series of controls on my form and perform the same calculation on all of them.

I have tried putting the controls in a panel, with the intention of looping through the panel however I am getting an error saying "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Panel' because 'Panel' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'".

I am very new to c# and ASP.NET and programming in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below I have included the code in my .aspx file that I am currently working in.

```
<div>
        <asp:Panel ID="AgilityLabels" runat="server">
        <table class="skillTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Lvl</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Exp</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Gnome Stronghold</td>
                <td class="exp">86.5</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="#ofActions"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Draynor Village Rooftop</td>
                <td class="exp">120</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="#ofActions"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Al Kharid Rooftop</td>
                <td class="exp">180</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>Varrock Rooftop</td>
                <td class="exp">238</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>Canifis Rooftop</td>
                <td class="exp">240</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Falador Rooftop</td>
                <td class="exp">440</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>Seer's Village Rooftop</td>
                <td class="exp">570</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>Pollnivneach Rooftop</td>
                <td class="exp">890</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>Rellekka Rooftop</td>
                <td class="exp">780</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>Ardougne Rooftop</td>
                <td class="exp">793</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
```

As you can see I have an asp:label control in one of the table cells, I am trying to perform the same calculation on each of the labels or really just perform a calculation on the data in that cell using c#.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in all practical cases, I would have to think that the data comes from a database or some data source. (can't really suggest that a hard coded list of values on a page makes all that much sense).

So, I would suggest that your designs "assume" that you working with a data table. I mean, a table of things in software land? Well, that's a table of data, and thus any of your efforts in terms of design, code, and general approach to ANY  software (even non web based) should be based on this concept of a table in code, and then you have asp.net take that table and display that table. We don't hand code this kind of stuff anymore - and maybe some person new to HTML "101" might approach things this way, but in asp.net, we as a general rule don't have to approach such problems this way.

But, the beauty, the fantastic part about asp.net is all this rich server side controls and choices we have. And as you see, by choosing the correct asp.net control, then we can quite much save world poverty's in terms of loading, displaying data, and even allowing a user to edit data, or even send the changes back to the database in ONE shot!

So, I would suggest that you use say a gridview, or even a listview, or a repeater (they in fact all work the same).

lets go with a listview - they have near un-limited flexbiity for these kinds of things.

BUT MOST important? By using these server side controls, then you have GREAT ease with code behind to process, update, and write code that works against repeating data - such as your problem is.

If you don't use server side controls, then you don't have a lot of "easy" to use controls for the code behind. This "concept" is what drives the asp.net development cycle, and once grapsed, you be amazed at how little code you have to write here.

So, lets use a listview - as noted, a grid view might be less mark up - but I find them about the same.

So, our markup could/would look like this:

```
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Lvl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lvl") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Action" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Action") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Exp" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Exp") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Amount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Amount") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server">lvl</th>
                    <th runat="server">Action</th>
                    <th runat="server">Exp</th>
                    <th runat="server">Amount</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Now, our code to fill out this view cna be this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
        LoadGrid2();
}


public void LoadGrid2()
{
    DataTable rstTable = new DataTable();
    rstTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Lvl", typeof(int)));
    rstTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Action", typeof(string)));
    rstTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Exp", typeof(decimal)));
    rstTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(decimal)));

    rstTable.Rows.Add(1, "Gnome StrongHold", 86.5, 0);
    rstTable.Rows.Add(10, "Draynor Village RoofTop", 120, 0);
    rstTable.Rows.Add(20, "Al Khand Roof Top", 180, 0);

    foreach (DataRow myRow in rstTable.Rows)
        myRow("Amount") = myRow("Exp") * 1.5;

    ListView1.DataSource = rstTable;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
}
```

So, now when we run this, we get:

[image]

And we could put all the data say in a database. So, now our loadGrid would look like this:

```
public void LoadGrid()
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,Lvl, Action, Exp, Amount from tblParts", new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        DataTable rst = new DataTable();
        rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);
        ListView1.DataSource = rst;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

So start thinking of the data as a SEPERATE thing from the markup. So create,load up a data table, and THEN send that data table to the display (listview, gridview, repeater) etc.

So, note how we procesed the data in the table, and then sent the table to the listview.

However, we could and can directly modify and loop the list view also. Say we wanted to multiple the Exp value by 2 times.

Then we can use this code:

```
protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (ListViewDataItem lRow in ListView1.Items)
{
    TextBox MyAmount = lRow.FindControl("Amount");

    MyAmount.Text = MyAmount.Text * 2;
}
}
```

So you can now loop and process the listview (or repeater, or gridview) as a table like structure - and no need for a WHOLE bunch of funny ways to reference the controls - they are clean, plane jane, and you can thus as a developer concentrate on writing code - not how you reference controls on the web page.

if you want, try this with a grid view. our TOTAL markup is now this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
```

And our code is the same, - bind the grid view, and we get this output:

[image]

Note how now our mark up was NEXT to nothing!!!

And to process each row, you can do this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow lRow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    TableCell MyAmount = lRow.Cells(3);

    MyAmount.Text = MyAmount.Text * 2;
}
}
```

so if you don't use templated fields, then you have to use/reference by "cells" collection - not the name. So this again is why I often use a listview - it is a bit more markup - but you are free to drop in quite much any valid asp.net control for the grid (list) column - that includes check boxes, picture controls - and even custom controls can be repeated over and over.

So, Gridview certainly can be a LOT less markup - but you tend to give up the ease in which each control of the row is a asp.net control.

***Edit: ***********************

Ok, so the user wants some event (we could even use the text box changed event), but for this solution, lets just drop in a button on the list view, and thus we have this mark up:

```
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Lvl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lvl") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Action" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Action") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Exp" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Exp") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Amount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Amount") %>' /></td>

                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" 
                        CommandName="MyUpdate" 
                        CommandArgument = '<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server">lvl</th>
                    <th runat="server">Action</th>
                    <th runat="server">Exp</th>
                    <th runat="server">Amount</th>
                    <th runat="server">Update</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

note how we added a command name, and a argument (that passes the row index)

So, now our view looks like this:

[image]
So, now in code behind, we can use the item command event.

We get this:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

// take Exp amount, divive by 2, and put reuslt in Amount field.

int rowIX = e.CommandArgument;
ListViewDataItem lRow = ListView1.Items(rowIX);

TextBox tExp = lRow.FindControl("Exp");
TextBox tAmount = lRow.FindControl("Amount");

tAmount.Text = tExp.Text / (double)2;
}
```

So we can quite much do anything we want in regards to that one row - it REALLY comes down to the kind of UI we want. I mean, we need SOME event to trigger our row code and actions - so now this is really a UI choice and whatever one likes or wants to occur here.

Comment: Everything was much more effective than what I was doing, and I learned a lot along the way.  The only thing that doesn't seem to be working for me is in the foreach loop where you set myRow("Amount") = myRow("Exp") * 1.5;  I'm getting an error on 'myRow' saying "Method Name Expected".  Am I missing something, or am I supposed to do something else in order to select the "Amount" column?

Comment: Well, it depends on where and when you want to run that loop. As noted, you can do the loop process in the table BEFORE you do the data bind. However to loop/process the gridview/listview/repeater controls (they all work the same) after? Then you have to bind the data to the grid first. however, this in most cases means you have to use the item data bound event for each row. So it comes down to when/where you need or want the row processing to occur.  But yes, take time to study the over all design approach - since you can and use this concept for just about every web page with repeating data

Comment: I need to process the row in a click event that happens after the user inputs some data but I don't know how to access this data table outside of the LoadGrid() method, if this makes sense, I'm not terribly certain how to describe it. As far as the design approach, I will definitely keep this as a reference for years to come.

Comment: Ok, but is this click event to run against all rows, or is there say to be some button on the single row, and we want the code to run against that given row? As noted, the user can update and change any and all values in that "view", and then the question becomes when and at what point the user action is to cause code to run. (we could drop in a button for each row), or as noted, the "save" example shows how to loop over each row and grabbing/getting a control from the one row.

Comment: Essentially, this click event takes two numbers the user enters into a text box, performs a calculation and outputs a result (this all works well).  I then need to take that result, divide it by the values in the "Exp" column and output the result of that to the "Amount" columns, all in the same event.  Basically I need to access the data in the "exp" column in each row in order to manipulate the "amount" column in each row when the aforementioned button is clicked.  I apologize for the lack of specificity, I hope this relays more effectively what I am trying to do.

Comment: Ok, see my edit - I outline the "general" idea and concept you can use to operate  on one row.